# How to get all records NOT found from query and how to do a word search from Excel list?

Tags: sql

I'm learning SQL on the fly today and have successfully run a SQL query.  Now I want to run another query from the table to include all records not included in the first query.  How do I do this?  I tried using:

`WHERE Not table1.field1 = query1.field1`

but wound up with like 5 million records, when I only have 8000 to start.

Second question is, I have a list of words in Excel.  I want to be able to run a query to include records where a field contains these words.  I am searching an address that spans multiple fields for keywords.

Comment: Ask your second question as a separate question.  Putting multiple unrelated points into one thread is bad, because it interferes with the Stack Overflow mechanism for selecting the bast answer.

Answer (score 1):

it's easy:

```
SELECT <fields>
FROM Table1
WHERE Field1 NOT IN (SELECT Field1 FROM Query1)
```

Comment: tried you code and it didnt work. The first query found about 800/8000 records so the second query should find the other 7200.  SELECT FF.*
FROM FF
WHERE FF.[Num]  NOT In (SELECT FF_MC.[Num] FROM FF_MC);

Comment: @riotburn - You are assuming that the count is relevant.  If your `field1` isn't unique and repeats, counts will be higher or lower depending on distribution.

Comment: It is unique, I setup the data to make sure that it is.

Comment: So how many are being returned by the second query?

Comment: about 1,000.  Is there another way to do it?  It so easy in excel, vlookup, and copy the N/A's :)  Need to do it in access though...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT temp.id, temp.name
FROM(
        (   /* your first query */
            SELECT table1.id AS id, table1.name AS name
            FROM mytable AS table1
            WHERE (CONDIDION)
        )
        UNION   /* combine both queries, make sure their columns match */
        (   /* your second query with the records not included in the first  */
            SELECT table2.id AS id, table2.name AS name
            FROM mytable AS table2
            WHERE (CONDIDION)
        )
    ) AS temp;
```

It's bit verbose, but I think it is more self explanatory. Your question is a little bit ambiguous so might also want this answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT temp.id, temp.name
FROM(
        (   /* select all rows in your first table */
            SELECT table1.id AS id, table1.name AS name
            FROM mytable AS table1
        )
        EXCEPT  /* use except or your language equivalent */
                /*make sure their columns match */
        (   /* put your first query here  */
            SELECT table2.id AS id, table2.name AS name
            FROM mytable AS table2
            WHERE (CONDIDION)
        )
    ) AS temp;
```